# The intersection of closed subspaces of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to prove that if there exists a finite dimensional closed subspace $M$ of a Hilbert space (say $X$) such that the intersection of the orthogonal complement of $M$ with another closed subspace of Hilbert space (say $Y$) is non trivial, i-e $M^\perp\cap Y\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: It is possible. If $M$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $X$, then $X$ can be written as a direct sum of the form $X=M\oplus M^\perp$. So any closed subspace $N\neq M$ of $X$ should give you the desired property.

Comment: @CheeHan: try $M=\{(x,0): x\in\mathbb C\} $, $Y=\{(x,x): x\in\mathbb C\} $.

Comment: Also, note that the intersection of subspaces is never empty.

Comment: Fair enough, the OP originally said non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M $ be any closed subspace. Take nonzero $x\in M $, $y\in M^\perp $, and let $$Y=\{\lambda (x+y):\ \lambda\in\mathbb C\}. $$ Then $M\cap Y=\{0\} $, $M^\perp\cap Y=\{0\} $.

Comment: Actually i need to prove that  M⊥∩Y≠{0}.and y is also closed subspace of Hilbert space

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. What is $Y $?

Comment: Y is another closed subspace of Hilbert space ,and dim M<dim Y.here M is finite dimensional.